# Q is denumerable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to reconstruct the proof that Q is denumerable by using finite cartesian product of countable sets is countable

Comment: Why would you be taking a Cartesian product to construct $Q$?

Comment: I want to use a set (say A) which is countable and hence by above its cartesian product A^n is countable and i want to show that there is a bijection between the cartesian product and Q

Comment: Hmm right, I wouldn't know so

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any clever bijection from a cartesian product of "simple" countable sets to $\mathbb{Q}$, but it can be proven if you know the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is at most countable, because the map $\mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}) \to \mathbb{Q}$, $(p, q) \mapsto \frac{p}{q}$ is surjective. But it is also at least countable, since every rational number can uniquely be written as $\frac{p}{q}$ where $q$ is a positive integer, $p$ is an integer and $p, q$ are coprime. The maps $\frac{p}{q} \mapsto q$ is then a surjection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$.

The Schröder-Bernstein theorem now yields that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: Can't you also argue that $\mathbb{Q}$ is at least countable since there is a natural injection of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ by $n \mapsto \frac{n}{1}$? Seems a bit simpler to me than using your surjection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @dioid This is possible as well, I just wanted to use two surjections so both directions seem similar.